# Bash $PS1 collapsing in MAC terminal

Tags: bash, prompt

So I have declared as `PS1="\[\W \u\e[0;31m\] ❤ \e[0m\] "` in my ~/.profile file. At the start my terminal look like this `~ mihkel ❤` - what is the desired output.
But when I'm going back in historly with up arrow it collapses in : `~ mihll` should show `~ mihkel ❤ ll`
I've tried few other versions - of PS1 without spaces etc - but still something like this happens.

Anyone know what's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
PS1="\W \u \[\e[00;31m\] ❤ \[\e[00m\] "
```

Comment: This is the same problem, and the same cause, as at http://superuser.com/a/860538/38062 and  http://superuser.com/a/695350/38062 .